# PdfTron CORS Error while implementing Form field detection

Tags: reactjs, pdftron

I am trying to implement "Form Field Detection" in my react application.

As per the documentation, I have tried to call the API but it thrown CORS error

Can anyone help on this?

Official Doc: https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/extraction/text-extract/#form-field-detection

Error:

Access to fetch at 'https://ai-serve.pdftron.com/recog/predict' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The even more interesting thing is the second error below the CORS one. Statuscode 502 indicates that the actual webservice that's supposed to handle the detection is not currently running. If you send the same fetch request on the docs page you linked, you do not get a CORS error but just a plain 502 response. Since the webservice is not running, it cannot send the required headers for your browser to accept the request and it prints the CORS warning. Best way to move forward would be to either check again in a couple hours or days, if you can wait that long or contact PDFTron about the issue

Answer (score 0):

It appears the Demo server for field detection had an issue but that has now been resolved, as the [demo](https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/demo/field-detection) works as expected. Using the below code sample from the guide you linked I was able to get a response:

```
// Fetch example
fetch('https://ai-serve.pdftron.com/recog/predict', 
    {
      method: 'POST',
      body: originalFile,
      headers: 
      {
        "File-Name": originalName || 'mypdf.pdf',
        "Task": "form",
        "Output-XFDF": true,
        "Output-JSON": true
      }
    })
     .then(resp => resp.blob())
     .then(this.handleResp) // handle the zipped response data
```

One thing to note is that this server is for demo purposes only, and should not be used in an application in production. Please visit [PDFTron.AI](https://www.pdftron.com/document-understanding/) to learn more about using artificial intelligence for document understanding, and reach out to PDFTron for how to license this product and deploy your own servers for your application.